# Using Powershell in Excel to check all cell values in column to trigger copy and paste per row

Tags: excel, powershell, if-statement, cell, copy-paste

I have a spreadsheet with 2 date columns with only one date value in either of them per row. Having two columns for this is redundant for my purposes so I would like to run a powershell script to check every cell in the Date2 column and if blank, copy the Date1 value on the same row to the Date2 column. That's the part I can't work out; To check all cells in the Date2 column and if blank, copy the adjacent Date1 value over.
Once that's done, I'll delete the Date1 column.
NOTE: The Date2 column has more dates so using it as the primary column to keep (less copy/pasting).
TIA

```
Example Test.xlsx:
         A            B
1 |    Date1   |    Date2   |
2 | 01/01/1900 |            |
3 | 01/01/1900 |            |
4 |            | 01/01/1900 |
5 |            | 01/01/1900 |
6 | 01/01/1900 |            |
7 |            | 01/01/1900 |
```

```
$Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application -Property @{Visible = $false} # Start Excel and hide the window
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $False # Disable comfirmation prompts
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open(C:\Temp\Test.xlsx) # Open spreadsheet file

#This is the part I'm stuck on:
#If cell in column Date2 is empty, then copy the adjacent Date1 value to the Date2 cell - This is done until at the end of the columns

[void]$Workbook.Sheets.Item("Test").Cells.Item(1, 1).EntireColumn.Delete() # Deleting "Date1" column
$Workbook.Save() # Save changes
$Workbook.Close($true) # Close workbook
$Excel.Quit() # Quit Excel
[Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel) # Release COM
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need in your code is a loop through the rows and update the cell in Column 2 (B) if empty with the value of Column 1 (A).

Try

```
$Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application -Property @{Visible = $false} # Start Excel and hide the window
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $False # Disable comfirmation prompts
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Test\Test.xlsx") # Open spreadsheet file
$Sheet    = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item("Test")

# get the total number of rows in the sheet
$rowCount = ($Sheet.UsedRange.Rows).Count
# update cell values in a loop
for ($row = 1; $row -le $rowCount; $row++) {
    $value = $Sheet.Cells.Item($row, 2).Text
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($value)) {
        # copy the cell format first; then the value
        $Sheet.Cells.Item($row, 2).NumberFormat = $Sheet.Cells.Item($row, 1).NumberFormat
        $Sheet.Cells.Item($row, 2) = $Sheet.Cells.Item($row, 1)
    }
}

[void]$Sheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).EntireColumn.Delete() # Deleting "Date1" column
$Workbook.Save() # Save changes
$Workbook.Close($true) # Close workbook
$Excel.Quit() # Quit Excel

# clean up COM objects
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Sheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Hi Theo, that worked thanks but the dates that copied across lost their date format; 01/01/1900 copied over as '1'. Do you know how to set the cell to be in date format?

Comment: I got it! I added an extra line at the end of the if statement in the for loop:

$Sheet.Cells.Item($row, 2).NumberFormat = "d/MM/yyyy"

# Only one 'd' to get rid of leading zeros. I need to test in January to confirm if the rest of my code wants M or MM for month. Cheers

Comment: @S.Hampton I have updated the code to also copy the original cell NumberFormat. This makes it more generic and you don't have to figure out what that format was yourself by trial and error. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Is this a recurring task? If not, using excel functions might be quickier.

Anyways, for excel data manipulation, I highly recommend using the [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) module

So you would read the sheet with both columns as properties, create a third property based on a ternary operation of the first two.